# Why firebase functions console printing log very late?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Firebase cloud is printing log in CLOUD CONSOLE very late. It's almost a delay of one & half hour .What is the reason for it? I have experienced this many time, which makes my work to be halted. can somebody please provide me the solution.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry you're having problems.  There are currently problems with Google infrastructure that are causing problems for some services.  You can stay up to date on the [Firebase status page](https://status.firebase.google.com/).

Comment: Hey @Doug is there any thing we can do?

Comment: @JOt it may have worked now https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Functions/18009

Comment: I have multiple projects with complete use of services at UScentral1 location and none of them is affected anyhow and the performance seems standard -> the status page might be misleading in some cases I guess.

Comment: The impact of any given issue may affect all projects or just some projects.  That fact may not be represented in the status page.  You are always free to report a problem to Firebase support: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: Not much you can do.  I am personally affected by this as well, as I'm unable to work on materials that I'm presenting in a couple weeks.  And I'm way behind.  :-(

Comment: @Doug Stevenson - exactly for this reason I keep mockup of my Firestore in local json and have also backup directory to run functions locally -> in case the service is down, I switch to local. It is also good to test function which would potentially stretch the limits of my subscriptions.